# Displaying webserver obtain JSON data into ListView

Tags: php, android, json, listview

I have been searching for solutions to solve this problem, but i just can't seems to find one. The JSON data format i have obtain is different from the other examples i found.

This is an example of the JSON data i have obtained from the php(inside a web server):

```
{"cols":[

{"label":"time","type":"datetime"},
{"label":"Temperature","type":"number"}],

"rows":[

{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 9, 14, 14, 8, 50)"},{"v":23.02}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 9, 14, 14, 12, 1)"},{"v":23.02}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 9, 14, 14, 12, 3)"},{"v":23.02}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 9, 14, 14, 12, 5)"},{"v":23.02}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 9, 14, 14, 12, 7)"},{"v":22.54}]},
...
```

I am not the one who created that PHP file and i am unable to change anything from it.

I tried using JSONParser like all the examples do, but its not working. How can I parse the data out and display it on a ListView?

Comment: "The JSON data format i have obtain is different from the other examples i found". You will probably never find such an example. My first thought would be, lets write my own parser! With `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.JSONArray` for example. Did you try that?

Comment: No, I am quite new to android and this is my first time i am trying to connect to a WebServer and using JSON. I manage to connect to the server and I understand the coding of the other examples but I have no idea how to start on the JSON parsing coding myself

Comment: Then I suggest you to try it. If you retrieved the JSON from the webservice, start like this: `JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonString);`. Using the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` I mentioned before (read the docs...), you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: By the way, if you ask another question on this site, you should include more details of the research you did before asking the question. People will take those questions more serious.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to the following:

```
public String getDataString() {
    String someString = "";

    JSONObject jsonObj = getData();
    Log.i("JSON string =>", jsonObj.toString());

    String text= null;

    try {
            // Handle cols
            JSONArray cols = jsonObj.getJSONArray("cols");
            int i = 0;
            Log.i("i", i+ "," + cols.length() ); //TODO delete this
            while(i<cols.length()) {

                JSONObject obj= cols.getJSONObject(i);
                String labelType = obj.getString("label");

                if(labelType.equals("time"))
                {
                    text = obj.getString("datetime");
                }
                else if(labelType.equals("Temperature"))
                {
                    text = obj.getString("number");
                }

                // Do something with String text

                i++;
            }
            // Handle rows
            JSONArray rows= jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
            int i = 0;
            Log.i("i", i+ "," + rows.length() ); //TODO delete this
            while(i<rows.length()) {

                JSONObject obj= rows.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray cObj= obj.getJSONArray("c");
                JSONObject vFirst = cObj.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject vSecond = cObj.getJSONObject(1);

                String firstString = vFirst.getString("v");
                String secondString = vSecond .getString("v");

                // Do something with String firstString and/or String secondString

                i++;
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("testing","Failed to load JSON");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
. 
.
.
// Return some string
return someString;
. 
.
.
}


public static JSONObject getData() {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("YOUR_URI_HERE");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gson Library from google to parse JSON Objects directly into Java Objects .